# Gender Prediction from Offline Handwriting Using Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network

Starting from the fact that handwritten documents style are gender-dependent (male and female have different writing styles), I'm trying to predict writer's gender from its handwritten scripts using Convolutional Neural Network (CNN). I choose the IAM and KHATT datasets for English and Arabic respectively.  After I read research articles related to this problem, I realized that few of them used deep learning (with handwritten word and/or sentence as input to CNN) and the majority used classic methods like (LBP, HOG, GLCM, SFTA), the state of the art accuracy is 80.79% and 85% (for CNN and classic methods respectively), I also read this [Article](https://www.etsmtl.ca/ETS/media/ImagesETS/Labo/LIVIA/Publications/2012/Hanusiak_IJDAR_2012.pdf) about identifying/verifying writer from its handwritten scripts which uses texture blocks from the written documents that give good results. 
As data preprocessing I used the method of texture blocks, after line and word segmentation, i constructed texture image from handwriting words, and segment the texture image to texture blocks of size 100*100px.

I used 60 writers per gender for training (which give 42,000 texture blocks), and 7 writers per gender for validation (which give 4,000 texture blocks) and 7 writers per gender for testing (which give 4,000 texture blocks).

I'm using TensorFlow and Keras as framework, I started with simple (LeNet-like architectures) for base line, I got 60% test accuracy. As a second approach, I used different state of the art architecture in image classification like (VGG16, VGG19, RESNET34, RESNET50) and I got 64% test accuracy.

So, my questions are:

1. How to reduce overfitting though I tried regularization methods (Dropout, L1, L2, Batch Norm) to reduce overfitting ?
2. I observed high variance in accuracy, if I re-shuffle the data (e.g from 64% to 50%) ?
3. How to modify CNN architectures to (multi-input CNN) to make the decision on multiple texture blocks, instead of one?

texture blocks of females: [image]

texture blocks of males: [image]

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Perhaps: try getting data from a much larger number of writers, for example, 10x, 100x more. If labelled data is hard to get, perhaps there are some similar data sets which you could use for transfer learning.

Comment: yes it would be better to find more labeled data. Unfortunately there isn't. @Valentas could you point me to some CNN models trained on this type of problems